# Expand and collapse a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a content `DIV` to expand and to collapse according to their contents.

Before expand it should be like this - 
[image]

After expand it should be like this - 
[image]

I am not sure how to use jquery for this. Tried with `toggle` class but couldn't get it to work.

This is my all code so far - http://jsbin.com/bicenomi/1/edit

Hope someone will help me.

Thank You.

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev can't you see images?

Comment: Try building a simple example, then post your jQuery code so far, and a reduced demo to reproduce the particular issue you have.

Comment: yeah really cant see images

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FB3x9.jpg
http://i.stack.imgur.com/QF0u4.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You may put the extra content in a Div. and make it display: none at beginning, and once a user clicks on View Details just toggle its display to display:block.

and if user clicks on Collapse, make div display:none again.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HideInfo() {

            var Chck = document.getElementById('ViewCollapse');
            alert(Chck.innerHTML);
            if (Chck.innerHTML == "Collapse") {

                document.getElementById('MoreInfo').style.display = 'none';
                Chck.innerHTML = "View";

            }
            else if (Chck.innerHTML == "View") {
                alert('view');
                document.getElementById('MoreInfo').style.display = 'block';
                Chck.innerHTML = "Collapse";

            }
        }
    </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

         <div class="timetable">


                  <h5><i class="icon fa fa-circle"></i><strong>xxxxxxxxxx</strong></h5>
                  <h6><small>No words</small></h6>
                  <h5><small>No words found in this</small></h5>


                  <h5><strong>xxxxxxxxxx</strong></h5>
                  <h6><small>No words</small></h6>
                  <h5><small>No words found in this</small></h5>

             <div id="MoreInfo">
                  <h5><i class="icon fa fa-circle"></i><strong>xxxxxxxxxx</strong></h5>
                  <h6><small>No words</small></h6>
                  <h5><small>No words found in this</small></h5>


                  <h5><strong>xxxxxxxxxx</strong></h5>
                  <h6><small>No words</small></h6>
                  <h5><small>No words found in this</small></h5>
           </div>

         </div>
         <div class="viewmore">
             <p class="small"><span>Medium:</span> No words</p>
             <p onclick="HideInfo();" id="ViewCollapse" class="small">Collapse</p>
         </div>

</body>

</html>
```

i just create a small demo. it works for me, Please try it and tell me does it solves your problem

Comment: Still I can not get it to work.

Comment: What exactly you want. please elaborate your problem. and whats wrong in this demo.

Comment: I am looking for solution using `jquery` - this is my code so far http://jsbin.com/bicenomi/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

Check out the demo below

http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/eK8X5/7/

JS

```
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am not looking a solution like `Accordion`. see my images, you can get an idea.